# Is there a way to hide User procedures and its code in visual foxpro9

Tags: visual-foxpro, visual-foxpro-9

I have 2 version of visual foxpro project 1 has both pjx file and exe file but the another one only contains exe file. when I open project 1 I can easily see all forms in project menu.
If I modify a form of project 1 I see the designer and can also see the user procedures present in that form, but if I try to open the form of another project I can see the designer but the user procedures and code behind is completely blank, project 2 has some user procedures because exe works completely fine but I cannot view the logic of it.

So I want to know is there a way to hide the user Procedure and the code behind it and if yes how to hide and show it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code of Vfp `SCX` Form methods is normally being stored in their *.SCX/SCT files pair. Whereas the code of `Define Class` \ `EndDefine` Forms exists in their PRG files or in their compiled FXP files respectively.
So that after having done a Project `Build`, someone could theoretically damage SCX/SCT and PRG files by removing their code, and the previously built YourProject.EXE would still run. If so, an option to get the code back would be having backups.